First-order formulas with free variables and AC$^0$
In "Introduction to Circuit Complexity" by Vollmer, on page 138, he defines the language of a first-order formula $L_I(\phi)$ to be the set $\{ w \in ( \{0,1\} \times \mathcal{P}(V))^+: w \models \phi \}$ for an interpretation function $I$ and set of free variables $V$. He also defines the class $FO[\mathcal{R}]$ for a finite set of relations $\mathcal{R}$ to be all the sets $A \in L_I(\phi)$ for some interpretation and first-order formula $I, \phi$ where $\phi$ is interpreted using only relations from $\mathcal{R}$.
But on page 140, he proves $FO = AC^0$. Morally, I see the correctness of the result, but how can these sets be equal if $FO$ is a set of sets of "$V$-structures" (input words with assignments to free variables), while $AC^0$ is a set of sets of binary strings? In what sense can a formula with unbound variables define a language that is decided by a family of $AC^0$ circuits?
